# Get the path of sourced bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

There is my simple script that I try

> `#!/bin/bash
>   DIR="$(cd "$(dirname $0)" && pwd)"
>   echo $DIR`

When I execute it like `$ ./my_script.sh`, get the path correctly.
But, when I source it like `$ source my_script.sh`, it gets the path `/bin`

How can I get the path of script by source it?
What is the different between source and execute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between sourcing a a script and "running it" is that when you source it (using `source` or `.`), the script is executed in the current shell environment, while if you "run it", a new shell process is started.  You want to source scripts that you want would change the current shell environment. A script that is run in a separate shell process can *not* change the parent shell's environment.  By "environment" is meant, for example, values of shell and environment variables, the current working directory etc.

A script is usually written to either be sourced or to be executed in its own shell environment, but very seldom both.  A script that is made to be sourced is sometimes called a "dot-script" (since `.` is the standard command for sourcing such a script; `source` is a `bash` "alias" for `.`).

A dot-script being sourced by a `bash` shell can find its location by examining the first element of the `BASH_SOURCE` array:

```
printf 'My location: %s\n' "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
```

The directory path will be relative to the current working directory at the time of invoking `source` or `.` on the script.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this on FreeBSD?  `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` doesn't work.

Comment: @MiloDC If you use the `bash` shell, then this should work. If it doesn't, then you are either not using the `bash` shell, or you are trying to do something different from what the user in the question is doing (figuring out the script's location from within a dot-script). You may want to look at the question that this question is a duplicate of.